# Setting a Parent Node

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree

My tree class:

```
public class BT<E>{
   E value;
   BT<E> left, right;

       public BT(E value)
       {
          this.value=value;
       }   

       public BT (E value, BT left, BT right) 
       {
          this.value = value;
          this.left = left;
          this.right = right;
       }
  public Tree getLeft(){
      return left;}
   public Tree getRight(){
      return right;}
   public void setLeft(Tree ln){
      left = ln;}
   public void setRight(Tree rn){
      right = rn;}
   public Tree getParent(){
      return this;}
```

I recursively generate two trees in my main method. `T1` the main tree and `T2` a random subtree. 
I am able to randomly select a node in `T1` however I am not able to replace `T2` *AT* the randomly selected node in `T1`.

Since at a given node I'm only able to `setLeft()` and `setRight()` I do not know how to set at the current node I am at.

Even a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

**[EDIT]**
To clarify, based on the structure of my tree, how would one go about replacing a specific node with another seperate tree (sub-tree).

Comment: You have a method called getParent. I assume it should return the parent of the current node (and *not* what it currently does). After getting the parent, you can change the left or right of the parent as you wish.

Comment: @tmrlvi I do not want to change the left or right. I want to change the current node. So I need a setParent(Tree p) - but I'm not sure how to go about replacing a node with an entire tree.

Comment: A node is a tree, I don't see the problem

Comment: Like tmrlvi already stated, you need a pointer to the parent. Once you have it, you replace the appropriate link (left or right) with the root node of your subtree.

Comment: You don't even necessarily need a pointer to the parent. It may just require changing the algorithm to have a *lookahead* on the children while keeping a reference on their parent. Before changing the data structure, try adapting the algorithm. If it is not easy or not elegant, adapt the data structure

Comment: @Dici Based on the structure of my tree, how would one go about replacing a specific node, with a separate tree and that specific node?

Comment: I would like to see the algorithm for answering this

Comment: BTW are you aware your `getParent` method is wrong ?

Comment: @Dici yes I am. I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

Comment: @RK2015 you have the answer in my code, however I would have preferred fixing the algo. You don't always control the data structure and have to come up woth the right algorithm. Plus, it uses more memory

Answer (score 2):

You either have to fix your `getParent` method, or to fix your algorithm. Since I don't have your algo, I will show you the first option (which is not my favourite one) :

```
public class BT<E> {
   E value;
   BT<E> left, right, parent;

   public BT(E value) {
      this.value = value;
      this.parent = null;
   }   

   public BT (E value, BT left, BT right) {
      this.value = value;
      setLeft(left);
      setRight(right);
   }

   private static void setParentIfNotNull(BT<E> child, BT<E> parent) {
       if (child != null) child.setParent(parent);
   }

   public void setLeft(BT<E> left) {
       this.left = left;
       setParentIfNotNull(left, this);
   }

   public void setRight(BT<E> right) {
       this.right= right;
       setParentIfNotNull(right, this);
   }
   // getters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove (or replace) an arbitrary node, you need to update its parent.  So first call `.getParent()`, then you need to figure out which side your target node resides, left or right, by calling `parent.getLeft() == nodeToRemove` (and the same for `.getRight()`, if you want).  Once you know if it's left or right, call the appropriate `.set...()` method.

I didn't initially notice that your `.getParent()` method returns the current node (`this`).  That is incorrect; the parent node is the node that *points to* `this`.  If you cannot fix your `.getParent()` implementation you'll need to change your algorithm to keep track of the parent node while you traverse the tree, like @Dici suggests.

Comment: `getParent` is clearly badly implemented here, a correct implementation would require an extra pointer to the parent, thus changing the data structure. I would rather try to change the agorithm first

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that.  I would go further than "badly" and say `getParent()` is *incorrectly* implemented.

Comment: Yeah, my english is sometimes a bit broken ! Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to correct your English.  "Badly" is certainly also true, though "incorrect" may be more clear.

Comment: You did not mean it but I do ! You're right it is the right word here, anyway